# JRIを使った平方根の結果が意図した通りにならない

Tags: java, r

JRIを使いJava上でRを使うことはできます。例として、以下のようなコードを打ってみました。

```java
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class JriTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--no-save"}, false, null);
        engine.assign("a", new int[]{49});
        REXP result = engine.eval("sqrt(a)");
        System.out.println(result.asDouble());
        engine.end();
    }
}
```

これは正常に

```
7.0
```

と表示されます。

しかし、これを整数として表示した場合に`asInt`にしましたが、`0`と表示されます。原因を教えてほしいです。その時には以下のプログラムを使用しました。

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class JriTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--no-save"}, false, null);
        engine.assign("a", new int[]{49});
        REXP result = engine.eval("sqrt(a)");
        System.out.println(result.asInt());
        engine.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: REXP インスタンスの中身は `getContent()` メソッドで取り出すことができて、それは `double[]`(array of double type) なので、`(int)((double[])result.getContent())[0]` とすれば可能です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そういう仕様だからです。
api仕様に以下の記述があります。

Returns:
int content or 0 if the REXP is no integer

整数値の値を持たない場合、0を返すとあります。double型のコンテンツは保持しているがintではないため、0を返しているのです。

https://www.rforge.net/org/docs/org/rosuda/JRI/REXP.html#asInt()

Comment: REXPをintの形にする方法はございますでしょうか？

Comment: 平方根を正数で受けたい要件がわかりませんが、キャストするのではだめですか？

Comment: そうですね。ひとまずはキャストにしておきます。ありがとうございます。